# convert dcraw to jpeg with imagemagick too dark/light

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, dcraw

I am using dcraw (http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) to handle camera raw files and piping it to imagemagick to convert it to a jpg for web use. I have done a few different test
and the jpeg never produces the exact same colours/brightness as I see in Adobe Lightroom 3. Even when I do just strait tiff from dcraw, the tiff doesn't have the same colour. So, i think there are a few things I need to tweak in the draw part of the command.

What is the best way to replicate correct colour and brightness of a raw file on a jpeg. I'm currently doing this:

```
dcraw -c -w 7_1337801236.orf | convert -compress lzw - 7_1337801236.jpg
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: thanks for that standalone `-` it tells `magick convert` to read input from the pipe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the same ImageMagick bug I've been hitting my head against, where once good convert commands now produce dark JPEGs. I've been waiting for months for a fix, and today when a new IM version hit Debian Sid but still didn't fix the issue, I started reading lots about colorspaces on the IM site. Sadly it's all very head-exploding and I found no clear instructions (all I tried broke dismally) how to make my JPEGs appear normal.

Then I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10567629) which suggests using a forked project called [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/). So in Debian all I had to do was:

```
apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
```

This pulls in the graphicsmagick package and removes imagemagick, but works seamlessly with no changes needed to my convert scripts. Happy camper!

HTH somebody :)